# How to map source columns to sink columns using select statement in Data flow using azure data factory

Tags: select, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow, mantis

Trying to create one pipeline for getting data from source to destination, using data flow transformation, using select statement. Here I struck we have a source column signal status map to sink side fit_crm_forecasrresolution and fit_crm_signalstatus.

I want source side 1 column with sink side 2 columns.
How can I map,
I want Singal status column records copy to sink side 2 columns.
But I'm getting only 1 column in sink side.

Comment: Please don't post picture like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source columns in the select settings contains duplicate columns and to achieve your requirement, you need to disable the **Skip duplicate input columns** setting in that.

[image]

Now, it will allow duplicate input columns and gives expected output.

[image]

Comment: Using select statement we will get correct out put, but after select statement I use derived column activity through pass the expression for 2 columns (i.e.fit_crm_signalstatus, & fit_crm_forecastresolution) I will get output.but our sink side duplicate records getting for 2 columns.

Comment: Upon looking on your dataflow, as your primary ask regarding the select transformation was resolved, I think it's better to raise a new question on this new ask with proper details like input, used transformations, expression, error and expected output for better understanding of the requirement. So that I can try from my end and the community might also assist.